# Call variable defined within function from another function without using global

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, return

I'm a beginner at python and this is my attempt at a quiz. the quiz is split into multiple sections and i would like their mark for each section displayed at the end.

This is the simplified version of my code. I don't know how to call a variable from another function and put it into the end, however i cannot use global variables or return as it would stop the function from executing my redo function. How would i do this? Thanks in advance!

```
def easy_questions(): 

    #questions

    if #answer correct
        score = score + 1
        question = question + 1
        break
    else:
        print#incorrect
        question = question + 1
        break

    Section_1 = str(score) + "/" + str(question)
    print("Your final mark for Section 1 is " + Section_1 + ".\n")

    run = redo()
    end()

def end(): #marks for each section

    while True:
        redo = input("Would you like to restart?\nEnter y/n: ")
        if redo == 'y':
            print("\n")
            easy_questions()
            break
        elif redo == 'n':
            #here is the problem, i cannot cannot call the variable
            print("You're final marks were:\nSection 1:" + Section 1 + "Section 2: " + #section 2 marks and so on) 
            quit()
        print("Please enter a valid input.\n")
    
def redo():
    while True:
        redo = input("Would you like to redo this section?\nEnter y/n: ")
        if redo == 'y':
            return True
        if redo == 'n':
            return False
        print("Please enter a valid input.\n")

easy_questions()
```

Comment: The indentation of the code in your question is all messed-up because you are doing it with tabs — which makes it unreadable. Please [edit] your question and fix this. I strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to pass variables of local scope between functions is with function parameters and return.

The way your code is structured is a bit all over the place. Redo is run in a lot of places and not run at all in end despite the code from it being run.

I have restructured it. One function manages the flow of the quiz. This calls another function that asks the questions and returns the score. This is then stored in an array of scores. If they choose to redo the section function is run again and the score in the array is changed.

```
    def qiuzMaster():
        scores = []
        noOfSections = 5
        #I don't know how you are managing questions so this may need to be changed
        for i in range (0, noOfSections):
            scores.append(easy_questions(i)) #where i is the section number
            redo = redo()
            while redo: #since redo is boolean don't need to compare it
                print("\n")
                scores[i] = easy_questions(i) #changes the score for section i
                redo = redo()
            for i in range (0, noOfSections):
            print("You're final marks were:\nSection",i+":",scores[i] #repeats for each section
        #done with section i. moves on to i+1
        quit() #quits when done with all the above sections


    def easy_questions(sectionNumber): 

    #questions for section

           if #answer correct
                score = score + 1
                question = question + 1
                break
            else:
                print#incorrect
                question = question + 1
                break

            finalScore = str(score) + "/" + str(question)
            print("Your final mark for Section 1 is " + finalScore + ".\n")

            return finalScore

    
    def redo():

        while True:
            redo = input("Would you like to redo this section?\nEnter y/n: ")
            if redo == 'y':
                return True
            elif redo == 'n':
                return False
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid input.\n")
```

Happy to explain my reasoning or how it works if you want.